# Selenium TimeoutException when try to getscreenshot

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have set up pageLoadTimeout to 30 secs. to my driver like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And in my entire code I have a method which take screenshot to browser:

```
try {
    String path = "logs/ss/";
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(path + createnamess() + ".jpg"));
}catch(Exception e41) {
    writelog("SCREENSHOT FAIL : " + e41.toString); //print message in txt file
}
```

Always when fail to take screenshot, in txt file appear:

> SCREENSHOT FAIL : org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout....

I can't understand why throw TimeoutException and how to fix it.

Comment: If you are using pageLoadTimeOut, and the page doesn't load within the specified time then it will throw TimeoutException. Try increasing the pageLoadTimeout.

Comment: I know this. But why is throwed when i try to getScreenshotAs? I don't try driver.get(...), or refresh or any action which make page load.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [*Java Docs*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html) [`pageLoadTimeout()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.

As you have set `pageLoadTimeout()` as follows :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

So whenever your intended webpage loading time elapses 30 seconds *TimeoutException* is thrown.

Now as per your code block, this *TimeoutException* is thrown much before the `try-catch {}` comes into play.

### How to fix it

To fix your *TimeoutException* issue you can consider any of the below mentioned approaches :

- Remove the `pageLoadTimeout()` completely and let the intended webpage take time to load.
- Put `driver.get(...)` with in `try{}` and incase of *TimeoutException* `catch{}` and exit as follows :

  ```
   try {
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
        //other code
   }catch(Exception e) {
        writelog("Page load Timeout Occured. Quiting !!!");
        driver.quit()
   }
  ```

Comment: How can my catch be triggered from outside?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your counter question. Keep the `driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")` with in the scope of `try-catch{}`. Keep rest of the code outside `try-catch{}`.

Comment: All my driver.get, refreshes and every action which load page are in try-catch block because of TimeoutException. Like this try{ load_page } catch{}. But I talk about try{}catch{} in question. What trigger TimeoutException if there is not a command which make to load page.